# how to consume webservices with amphp/artax?

Tags: php, amphp

i'm new to amphp/artax

I need to consume several web services in paralell, and join the answers togheter.

I achieved request several pages with :

```
                .... 
                $response = yield $client->request($uri);
                ....
```

how to get an example of a call to a web service ?

Best Regards

Comment: https://github.com/amphp/artax/tree/master/examples

Comment: hi @Chris-white but yes ! i read the examples, I even use 6-parallel-requests.php to test. this examples only fetch the body of web pages.

Comment: Hi @B001ᛦ yes, i allready call web services from php, with soapClient...